# windows universal app login/register from asp.net api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have two applications.
The first one is an asp.net mvc api, this application contains the users with local login/register and only facebook login.
The second one is a windows universal app.
On windows universal app I want to make the local login/register and facebook.

I've been looking for some references, but the only one that I found is to only connect the app to facebook. But I want to connect both login/register systems with api.

My questin is how can I make the both login systems working with my windows universal app (or some tutorial)?

Comment: Assume you use the token in the ASP.NET API call, you can leverage the WebAuthenticationBroker class by specify the StartUri and EndUri, in EndUri, return the token to the client application.

Comment: can you show me some examples please?